# PDO Query fetchAll remove keys but keep values including duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to add custom fields to my presentation platform and have the following MySQL/PDO query:

```
SELECT presenters.presenter_name,
       presenters.presenter_email,
       presenters.presenter_contact,
       presentations.presentation_uid,
       presentations.presentation_presenter_notes,
       presentations.presentation_date,
       presentations.presentation_customer_reference,
       presentations.presentation_customer_name,
       presentations.presentation_customer_email,
       customfields.customfield_name,
       customfields_data.customfield_data_value
    FROM presentations 
    INNER JOIN presenters ON presentations.presentation_presented_by = presenters.presenter_id 
    LEFT JOIN customfields ON customfields.customfield_presentation_uid = presentations.presentation_uid 
    LEFT JOIN customfields_data ON customfields_data.customfield_data_id = customfields.customfield_id
    WHERE presentations.presentation_uid = :presentation_id
```

I execute the query with `$presentation = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and then `print_r` the results and get the following:

```
Array (
     [0] => Array
         (
        [presenter_name] => John Doe
        [presenter_email] => john.doe@example.com
        [presenter_contact] => 0123456789
        [presentation_uid] => esljqpmdh
        [presentation_presenter_notes] => Great presentation
        [presentation_date] => 2015-06-05 14:17:15
        [presentation_customer_reference] => How to make a great presentation.
        [presentation_customer_name] => Doe John
        [presentation_customer_email] => doe.john@example.com
        [customfield_name] => Favourite Colour
        [customfield_data_value] => Blue
    )

     [1] => Array
         (
        [presenter_name] => John Doe
        [presenter_email] => john.doe@example.com
        [presenter_contact] => 0123456789
        [presentation_uid] => esljqpmdh
        [presentation_presenter_notes] => Great presentation
        [presentation_date] => 2015-06-05 14:17:15
        [presentation_customer_reference] => How to make a great presentation.
        [presentation_customer_name] => Doe John
        [presentation_customer_email] => doe.john@example.com
        [customfield_name] => Age
        [customfield_data_value] => 26
         )
)
```

What I am trying to achieve is this so that I can iterate through the custom fields and add them in to my view template:

```
Array (
        [presenter_name] => John Doe
        [presenter_email] => john.doe@example.com
        [presenter_contact] => 0123456789
        [presentation_uid] => esljqpmdh
        [presentation_presenter_notes] => Great presentation
        [presentation_date] => 2015-06-05 14:17:15
        [presentation_customer_reference] => How to make a great presentation.
        [presentation_customer_name] => Doe John
        [presentation_customer_email] => doe.john@example.com
        [customfield_name] => Favourite Colour
        [customfield_data_value] => Blue
        [customfield_name] => Age
        [customfield_data_value] => 26
    )
```

or better still:

```
Array (
        [presenter_name] => John Doe
        [presenter_email] => john.doe@example.com
        [presenter_contact] => 0123456789
        [presentation_uid] => esljqpmdh
        [presentation_presenter_notes] => Great presentation
        [presentation_date] => 2015-06-05 14:17:15
        [presentation_customer_reference] => How to make a great presentation.
        [presentation_customer_name] => Doe John
        [presentation_customer_email] => doe.john@example.com
        [customfields] => Array (
                  [customfield_name] => Favourite Colour
                  [customfield_data_value] => Blue
                  [customfield_name] => Age
                  [customfield_data_value] => 26
         )
    )
```

But I'm not sure what to do next, I'm completely stuck and not sure which part of my code is incorrect. The query or the fetchAll.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there any problem in having a bit of php array manipulation after the query and before displaying data? It seems the most reasonable thing to do, imho

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Not really, I am just not sure how to manipulate the array correctly due to the keys.

Comment: it much depend on what you need the array for. I'm trying for an answer in a minute

Comment: Sorry - i missed 1 part in the first attempt. Test it - It should works with multiple dual array for 1 people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you ok with associative arrays? Then create a new array (say `$def_presentation` or something ) and go for something like

```
foreach($presentation as $row) {
    if(!isset($def_presentation[$row['presentation_uid']])) {
        $def_presentation[$row['presentation_uid']] = $row;
        unset($def_presentation[$row['presentation_uid']]['customfield_name'],$def_presentation[$row['presentation_uid']]['customfield_data_value']);
        $def_presentation[$row['presentation_uid']]['customfields'] = array();
    } 
    $def_presentation[$row['presentation_uid']]['customfields'][$row['customfield_name']] = $row['customfield_data_value'];
}
```

Comment: This works great and I understand the code, however is it possible to change it so the output is this: `Array
(
            [presenter_name] => John Doe
            [presenter_email] => john.doe@example.com
etc..
)`

Comment: Now I see, I missed the fact that you are already filtering by `presentation_uid`. This make things even easier, look at [the fiddle](http://www.tehplayground.com/#FXk8Ji5oK)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @dirluca, the fiddle works perfectly. I just hope I am doing the right thing in querying the custom fields alongside everything else or if I should be putting them in a separate query and merging the arrays.

Comment: It looks ok to me. The only thing I would mind is performance if your database is expected to be a big one. In that case be very carefull with your index scheme in the db not to have long execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Et voila !
See [Demo](http://www.tehplayground.com/#HVdaTe6Jp)

**CODE :**

```
$res_non_associative = Array (
 0 => Array
     (
    "presenter_name" => "John Doe",
    "presenter_email" => "john.doe@example.com",
    "presenter_contact" => "0123456789",
    "presentation_uid" => "esljqpmdh",
    "presentation_presenter_notes" => "Great presentation",
    "presentation_date" => "2015-06-05 14:17:15",
    "presentation_customer_reference" => "How to make a great presentation.",
    "presentation_customer_name" => "Doe John",
    "presentation_customer_email" => "doe.john@example.com",
    "customfield_name" => "Favourite Colour",
    "customfield_data_value" => "Blue"
),

 1 => Array
     (
    "presenter_name" => "John Doe",
    "presenter_email" => "john.doe@example.com",
    "presenter_contact" => "0123456789",
    "presentation_uid" => "esljqpmdh",
    "presentation_presenter_notes" => "Great presentation",
    "presentation_date" => "2015-06-05 14:17:15",
    "presentation_customer_reference" => "How to make a great presentation.",
    "presentation_customer_name" => "Doe John",
    "presentation_customer_email" => "doe.john@example.com",
    "customfield_name" => "Age",
    "customfield_data_value" => 26
     )
);

// You won't have to do that - Proccess only coz i couldn't get the     
// associative array from fetchAll()
$res = array();
array_push($res, array_values($res_non_associative[0]));
array_push($res, array_values($res_non_associative[1]));


// Array that will be returned
$final_array = array();


// Depending how the result will be put in array
// Regarding your query it seems you catched 2 by 2
// Therefore we need a cursor to add into the final_array
$cursor = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < count($res); $i += 2)
{
    // We will push into main array all infos except "customfields"
    $main_array = array();
    $max_main_insert = count($res[$i]) - 2;

    for($j = 0; $j < $max_main_insert; ++$j)
    {
        array_push($main_array, $res[$i][$j]);
    }
    array_push($final_array, $main_array);

    // We will push into custom array all the "customfield"
    $custom_array = array();

    array_push($custom_array, $res[$cursor][$max_main_insert]);
    array_push($custom_array, $res[$cursor][$max_main_insert +1 ]);

    array_push($custom_array, $res[$cursor + 1][$max_main_insert]);
    array_push($custom_array, $res[$cursor + 1][$max_main_insert +1 ]);

    array_push($final_array[$i], $custom_array);

    ++$cursor;
}


print_r($final_array);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => John Doe
        [1] => john.doe@example.com
        [2] => 0123456789
        [3] => esljqpmdh
        [4] => Great presentation
        [5] => 2015-06-05 14:17:15
        [6] => How to make a great presentation.
        [7] => Doe John
        [8] => doe.john@example.com
        [9] => Array
            (
                [0] => Favourite Colour
                [1] => Blue
                [2] => Age
                [3] => 26
            )

    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative method, I think an associative array is easier to manipulate.

Comment: By default PDO:fetchall fetch arguments is set at PDO::FETCH_BOTH. that's why i commented u wont need to do primary stuff - It was to show you an example of the code running. With my solution you won't loose both keys but unset method will force you to use only associative keys.